# Using Java Stream anymatch with filter for null check

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am using Stream.anymatch to check if any of the four string is empty or null- Can we get handle to the list of Strings that are null  as a part of this check for subsequent logic

```
if(Stream.of(stringA, stringB,stringC, stringD)
        .anyMatch(field -> field == null || field.trim().isEmpty()))
```

Comment: Store `stream.filter(predicate).collect(toList())`, then check the result for emptiness.  You can't store the matching strings from anyMatch like you want.

Comment: What you mean by 'handle' to the list of strings ? You want the variable names which has null value??

Comment: what about storing the strings that are **not** null and from that you can find out the strings that are not contained in that list

Comment: I agree with @ChotaBheem. Can you confirm that you want to know the strings that are not null? Why, what are you going to do with a list of nulls? Have you tried `Collectors.partitioningBy(field -> field == null || field.trim().isEmpty())`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use StringUtils.isBlank() from Apache Commons libraries https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Then you can use a temporary value to store Objects with blank values using

```
List<String> blank = Stream.of(stringA, stringB,stringC, stringD)
                           .filter(StringUtils::isBlank)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (blank.size() > 0) {
      // your code here
}
```

I suggest you use multiple if(StringUtils.isBlank(stringX)){} statements if you need to execute different code in each case.

Comment: You can also use more methods from Stream API like `anyMatch`, `noneMatch` like Sajna did in the question, and combine that with the method reference that you show in your `filter()` call